# iOS Animating main UIViewController's View height

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a text field pinned to the bottom of my main UIViewController's view (self.view), and when the user clicks on it this function is called (via a UIKeyboardWillShowNotification) which will alter the height of the self.view.frame:

```
-(void)keyboardWillShow: (NSNotification*) notification {
    NSDictionary* info = [notification userInfo];
    CGSize keyboardSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    CGFloat textFieldHeight = activeField.frame.size.height;
    CGPoint textFieldOrigin = activeField.frame.origin;
    textFieldOrigin.y += textFieldHeight;

    CGRect visibleRect = self.view.frame;
    visibleRect.size.height -= keyboardSize.height;

    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(visibleRect, textFieldOrigin)) {
        CGRect r = self.view.frame;
        r.size.height -= keyboardSize.height;

        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                     animations:^{
                         self.view.frame = r;
                     }];
    }
}
```

It resizes the self.view.frame fine, so it is all being called and run, but for some reason refuses to animate it over a second - it just appears in place immediately.

What do I need to do in order to animate this change in height?

Comment: are you using auto layout?

Comment: I think so.  I have the textfield pinned to the bottom, left and right of the UIViewController's view if that's what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have auto layout on you shouldn't change the frame directly, instead you should change on of the constrains. 
Add an IBOutlet to the constrain (the bottom constrain), and change the constant like so:

```
myTextFieldConstrain.constant -= YOUR_VALUE
```

Also, if you want it to animate, call `[YOURSUPERVIEW layoutIfNeeded];` after you change the constant.

Example:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                     animations:^{
                         myTextFieldConstrain.constant -= YOUR_VALUE;
                         [YOURSUPERVIEW layoutIfNeeded];
                     }];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to dispatch it with a slight delay, like:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                     animations:^{
                         self.view.frame = r;
                     }];
}
```

It usually makes the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I've tried this and it just appears in place 1 second later, i.e., still not animated.  I've put the animation duration up to 10 seconds and the resizing takes place immediately.